# Ribbon with bootstrap

Tags: ribbon

I am trying to put a ribbon in a website using bootstrap but I can't get it show correctly.

Here is the basic html and css code - I use a ribbon online generator

```html
<div class="ribbon"><div class="ribbon-stitches-top"></div><strong class="ribbon-content"><h1>A Pure CSS Ribbon</h1></strong><div class="ribbon-stitches-bottom"></div></div>
```

```css
.ribbon {
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 20px!important;
   background: #d64b4b;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d64b4b), to(#ab2c2c));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d64b4b, #ab2c2c);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d64b4b, #ab2c2c);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d64b4b, #ab2c2c);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d64b4b, #ab2c2c);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d64b4b 0%, #ab2c2c 100%);
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.3) 0 1px 1px;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
.ribbon h1 {
   font-size: 25px!important;
   color: #801111;
   text-shadow: #d65c5c 0 1px 0;
   margin:0px;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   }
.ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   bottom: -1em;
   border: 1.5em solid #c23a3a;
   z-index: -1;
   }
.ribbon:before {
   left: -2em;
   border-right-width: 1.5em;
   border-left-color: transparent;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) 1px 1px 1px;
   }
.ribbon:after {
   right: -2em;
   border-left-width: 1.5em;
   border-right-color: transparent;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.4) -1px 1px 1px;
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before, .ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
   border-color: #871616 transparent transparent transparent;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   border-style: solid;
   bottom: -1em;
   content: '';
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:before {
   left: 0;
   border-width: 1em 0 0 1em;
   }
.ribbon .ribbon-content:after {
   right: 0;
   border-width: 1em 1em 0 0;
   }
.ribbon-stitches-top {
   margin-top:2px;
   border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   }
.ribbon-stitches-bottom {
   margin-bottom:2px;
   border-top: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
   }
```

I tried to put in `col-md-12 col-md-offset-4` but I can't get that it put in the center on the web and in lower screen resolution it doesn't show correctly, how can I improve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Top left corener is Ribbon over image.

```css
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-shadow.ribbon-right, .mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-shadow.ribbon-vertical-right {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-color-danger {
    background-color: #ed6b75;
    color: #fff;
}
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-shadow {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-right {
    left: auto;
    right: -2px;
}
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
 left:7px;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    z-index: 5;
}
.mt-element-ribbon .ribbon, .mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-color-default, .mt-element-ribbon .ribbon.ribbon-color-default>.ribbon-sub, .mt-element-ribbon .ribbon>.ribbon-sub {
    background-color: #bac3d0;
    color: #384353;
}
.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">    
   <div class="row">
       
      <div class=" mt-element-ribbon" align="center">
       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" class="img-responsive" alt="Image" >
          <div class="ribbon ribbon-left ribbon-shadow ribbon-color-danger uppercase">&#36;0000</div>
          
      </div>
    </div>
```